# Custom alert/confirmation box

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to make a custom `alert/confirm/prompt` that have the same behaviour as native javascript windows (**without** using callbacks/asynchronous events)?

Ex.:

```
if(mytest == true){

    myCustomMsgWindow('message'); //Pause execution
    //do something

}
```

I tried this once but dint works for confirm window because it must return a value.

Comment: This seems relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649777/equivalent-to-window-prompt-confirm-alert-as-pure-js-css-solution

Comment: this part of it isn't possible: `//Pause execution` however the rest is.

Comment: I don't think i have used a callback in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/XME7f/. Did you mean something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make custom ones but their **behavior will not be the same.**

Because in the browsers these boxes pause the execution thread, and resumed by user action. you can not pause the execution thread, this is implicit.

However there are some workaround which may behave almost similar. You can try that
[BootBox](http://bootboxjs.com/)

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot write JS code that blocks (pauses execution) waiting for user input on without `alert` or `confirm`. You have to listen for events within your dialog asynchronously (through events)

The solution is use callbacks as you have already mentioned, not sure why you don't want to use that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was just thinking... if this were possible, of course: Override the native confirm, alert and prompt methods, so these windows would looks the same in all browsers and also would be the easiest way to implement custom dialogs without replacing it all over your website page by page.