# Simple JavaScript quiz with radio buttons and multiple correct answers

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to make a simple quiz like so:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I would like to use a custom alert box, not the usual JavaScript one. So just a div that appears with my message inside.

Apologies if I do not have more to work with than the screenshots - I've looked at many other questions and bits of scripts, but I'm really interested in something simple that can push me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: I recommend taking a look at [jQuery's dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19818948/custom-alert-confirmation-box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.correct{max-width:100px;opacity:0}
input:checked.right ~div.correct{position:relative;background-color:yellow;top:-20px;left:70px;opacity:1;}
```

```html
<div >
  Which country is commonly called the U.S.A ?<br>
 England<input type="radio" name="one" value="UK" /><br>
  America<input type="radio" name="one" value="US" class="right"/><br>
  <div class="correct">Correct</div></div>
<div >
  Which country is commonly called the U.S.A ?<br>
 England<input type="radio" name="two" value="UK" /><br>
  America<input type="radio" name="two" value="US" class="right"/><br>
  <div class="correct">Correct</div></div>
<div >
  Which country is commonly called the U.S.A ?<br>
 England<input type="radio" name="three" value="UK" /><br>
  America<input type="radio" name="three" value="US" class="right"/><br>
  <div class="correct">Correct</div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try with JQuery. Then you could [show or hide](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp) the divs simply by using `$("#mydiv").show()` or `$("#mydiv").hide()`.